# Flex backgroundAlpha with black color

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am trying to do a video player with Adobe AIR Flex and utilizing StageVideo. In order to get StageVideo, the player is in actionscript file which is loaded into flex project on run time. To be able to display StageVideo, the backgroundAlpha has to set to 0. On main window, I am able to get black background by putting backgroundColor="#000000". However, on the secondary window, this seems like doesn't work. The background become white color.

At first I am planning to put a black rectangle at the back to cover the white background. But the problem is the video always loaded at the lowest level. I tried with `addElementAt` and `addChildAt` trying to push the video element in the front of that black rectangle, but it didn't work.

Main window code (shows black background):

```
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                   xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                   xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" applicationComplete="init(event)" showStatusBar="false" backgroundColor="#000000" backgroundAlpha="0">

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Second window code (shows white background):

```
<s:Window xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="init(event)" showStatusBar="false" backgroundColor="#000000" backgroundAlpha="0">

</s:Window>
```

So, how can I get the black background for my second window?
Thank you.

Comment: You try change the backgroundAlpha in the second windows?

Comment: If the backgroundAlpha is changed to 1, the video will not display.

Comment: I understand, maybe you would have to find a more natural way to do it.